# Rendered text magically disappears

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw, glm-math

Im currently preparing everything to write my own game in c++ using GLFW. I never wrote a game in c++ before only in C# using Unity. I'm completly new to GLSL. I found out how to render text and everything works basicly great but now I have a problem with (I think) the projection matrix. I used GLFWmonitor to get my screen resolution and ran my window on this resolutions:

```cpp
GLFWmonitor *monitor = glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();
const GLFWvidmode *mode = glfwGetVideoMode(monitor);
std::cout << "Monitor resolution: " << mode->width << "x" << mode->height << std::endl;
CBWindow window(mode->width, mode->height, "City Builder");
```

From the cout I get:

```
Monitor resolution: 1440x900
```

Then I started with the text renderer and used `glfwGetWindowSize` to get the window size and set the projection matrix to this size but something went wrong. As if the space where I can render text is only available in a fraction of my Window:
[image: Image of the text clipping the available space]

For debug reasons I started printing the width and height I get form the `glfwGetWindowSize` and i saw that's not 100% but it should work:

```
Window size: 1440x793
```

I don't know why I get this incorrect numbers and I dont know why I can't render on the complete screen.

Here is the function that is responsible for rendering the text:

```cpp
void TextRenderer::renderText(GLFWwindow *window, const std::string& text, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat scale, const glm::vec3& color) {
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    this->shader.use();
    int w, h;
    glfwGetWindowSize(window, &w, &h);
    std::cout << "Window size: " << w << "x" << h << std::endl;
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, static_cast<GLfloat>(w), 0.0f, static_cast<GLfloat>(h));
    this->shader.setUniform("textColor", color);
    this->shader.setUniform("projection", projection);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);

    // iterate through all characters
    std::string::const_iterator c;
    for (c = text.begin(); c != text.end(); c++) {
        Character ch = this->font.getCharacters().at(*c);

        GLfloat xpos = x + ch.Bearing.x * scale;
        GLfloat ypos = y - (ch.Size.y - ch.Bearing.y) * scale;

        GLfloat w = ch.Size.x * scale;
        GLfloat h = ch.Size.y * scale;

        // update VBO for each character
        GLfloat vertices[6][4] = {
                { xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0, 0.0 },
                { xpos,     ypos,       0.0, 1.0 },
                { xpos + w, ypos,       1.0, 1.0 },

                { xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0, 0.0 },
                { xpos + w, ypos,       1.0, 1.0 },
                { xpos + w, ypos + h,   1.0, 0.0 }
        };

        // render glyph texture over quad
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ch.TextureID);

        // update content of VBO memory
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        // render quad
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        x += (ch.Advance >> 6) * scale;
    }

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    this->shader.unuse();
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}
```

the fragment shader:

```c
#version 330 core

in vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D text;
uniform vec3 textColor;

void main()
{
    vec4 sampled = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, texture(text, TexCoords).r);
    color = vec4(textColor, 1.0) * sampled;
}
```

and the vertex shader:

```c
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec4 vertex; // <vec2 pos, vec2 tex>
out vec2 TexCoords;

uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
    TexCoords = vertex.zw;
}
```

The shader functions we use in the renderText method just uses `glUseProgram` and the functions to set uniforms.

Here is how I use the functions:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <glm/ext/matrix_clip_space.hpp>
#include "Display/Window.h"
#include "Renderer/Shader.h"
#include "vendor/stb/stb_truetype.h"
#include "Renderer/UI/Text/Font.h"
#include "Renderer/UI/Text/TextRenderer.h"

int main() {
    if(!glfwInit()){
        printf("Failed to initialize OpenGL\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    GLFWmonitor *monitor = glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();
    const GLFWvidmode *mode = glfwGetVideoMode(monitor);
    std::cout << "Monitor resolution: " << mode->width << "x" << mode->height << std::endl;
    CBWindow window(mode->width, mode->height, "City Builder");

    Shader shader("../assets/shaders/Text/vert.glsl", "../assets/shaders/Text/frag.glsl");
    Font font("../assets/fonts/Arial.ttf", 48);
    TextRenderer textRenderer(shader, font);

    double lastTime = glfwGetTime();
    int nbFrames = 0;
    std::string fps_text;

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window.GetWindow())){

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);

        double currentTime = glfwGetTime();
        nbFrames++;
        if ( currentTime - lastTime >= 1.0 ){ 
            fps_text = "FPS: " + std::to_string(nbFrames);
            nbFrames = 0;
            lastTime += 1.0;
        }

        textRenderer.renderText(window.GetWindow(),fps_text, 1400, 0, 1, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        textRenderer.renderText(window.GetWindow(),fps_text, 0, 790, 1, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

        glfwSwapBuffers(window.GetWindow());
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Using `glfwGetFramebufferSize` also doesnt work

Comment: What happens if you hardcore the width and the height to be 1440 and 900?

Comment: @newQOpenWid Doesnt work still same problem

Comment: Analyze (debug) the vertices in your `renderText` function. What happens if you set the viewport prior to rendering? Where do you load the `gl` functions?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the missing 107 pixels are used by the windows titlebar? It would make sense since you can't render text on the titlebar.
But it's just an assumption.

The monitor size is not the same as the window size.

If my assumption is correct you should try setting the window to fullscreen mode.
I hope this helps :)